# Porting SQLBase by Gupta to another system

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase

We use SQLBase for our development in various versions, including 12.2. Our main application is a Team Developer application (Version 7.5) that utilizes SQLBase as its database.

In addition to Team Developer, we program in C# (.NET Core). We're quite bothered by the fact that SQLBase still doesn't offer Entity Framework support. This means that we have to access the database using the old ADO.NET in our C# applications.

The issue is that we have a significant amount of code in Team Developer 7.5, which makes it not so straightforward to simply swap out the database. On the other hand, we don't want to continue developing with ADO.NET but rather with Entity Framework.

If we decide to replace the database, the challenge arises on how to access it from Team Developer without having to modify too much of the program code.

What needs to be done so we can use another database like MySQL, MariaDB, Postgre, or MS SQL Server with Team Developer 7.5? This way, we could finally access the database from .NET using Entity Framework while still utilizing the existing Team Developer code.

Thank you,

René

Comment: `We're quite bothered by the fact that SQLBase still doesn't offer Entity Framework support.` are you sure that's a bad thing

Comment: Yes, if one needs to develop software in the .NET environment alongside Team Developer.

Comment: Sorry Temuco - disagree.  Sure, Entity Framework may be Ok ( I have no idea ), but OLEdB works just fine against most dBMS vendors ( If you go for SqlServer use the MSOLEDBSQL driver, not the old SQLOLEDB  ) and Team Developer handles it well. Its fast and robust. Just  assign your connection string to the SqlUDL variable ( or a UDL file path) and away you go.  You don't need a SQL.ini at all, nor SqlUser, SqlPassword or SqlDatabase anymore.

Comment: Well, from C# applications I use ADO.NET and that's the point. I want to use the modern Entity Framework Core here. I save at least 40% program code, the typical errors when addressing columns are a thing of the past. I have full Intellisense support.  I don't have to worry about the type of parameters and I can use LINQ throughout. The programmes become more robust and they are finished faster.

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way affiliated with Gupta or SQLBase or any other dBMS vendor, but think twice and then think three times before downgrading from SQLBase.

We are going through this exact conundrum right now.
**NOT** because of the Entity Framework thing ( OLEdB  works just fine with SQLBase or SQLServer against TeamDeveloper, C# or what-ever ) and **NOT** because there is any issue what-so-ever with Gupta SQLBase ( in fact it outperforms SQLServer in some cases .)
But simply because Corporate in their wisdom say 'everything has to be standardized'.

So reluctantly have started the l-o-n-g process of migrating a 120Gb SQLBase, which works perfectly well,  and all its Stored procs, Triggers, Indexes, FK's, 100's of builtin @functions, keywords ( SYSDATETIME ... ) to SQLServer - again, against a LARGE Gupta TeamDeveloper code base.

You are exactly right - it not so straightforward to simply swap out the database.
Moving SQLBase v12.3 to SQLServer 2019 means a whole lot of work.
Main ones of note are:

1. Data types that are in slightly different formats e.g. TIME and LONG,  so not a straight like-for-like.
2. Before INSERT trigger. Only SQLBase manages this properly. Difficult to find an equivalent. Least of all, both ‘row-level’ and ’statement’ level types.        [Nice! SQLBase Before Insert Trigger](https://www.banksidesystems.com/gupta-sqlbase-%E2%80%93-a-%E2%80%98before-insert-trigger%E2%80%99-super-hero)
3. ETL. Unless you use some-sort of wizard ( like the SQLServer Import/Export wizard) to assist somewhat with Export/Transfer/Load, you will go crazy.
4. ROWID. No dbms has ROWID like SQLBase. So if your app uses ROWID be prepared for a bit of work in this area. If moving to SQLServer, the closest resemblance is ROWVERSION which is a binary(8) number which tracks a relative time within the dB, not an actual time. So throughout your TD code you potentially need to convert
   e.g.

Select ROWID:

```
Return VisStrChoose( gGetBrand(  ) = DBV_BRAND_MSSQL,
    'CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(BINARY(8),' || p_sROWIDColName || '), 2 )', 
     p_sROWIDColName )
```

Where ROWID:

```
Return VisStrChoose( gGetBrand(  ) = DBV_BRAND_MSSQL,
    'CONVERT(binary(8),\'0x\' + :' || p_sROWIDBindName || ' , 1)', ':' || 
     p_sROWIDBindName  )
```

After going through this entire ETL and TD code modification process, best advice is to think twice and then three times against migrating from SQLBase. I just can't justify the the cost, stress and risk against (no)performance gain, swapping connectivity ( when OLEdB does the job ). But no doubt there will be others who think differently I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your detailed answer, Steve.

I understand what you mean. The ROWID in particular causes us problems mentally, as we make extensive use of it. However, I would like to know how to address another SQL database from the Team Developer. How do you do that?

We have many other satellite applications around Team Developer that run on .NET - here I mean C# and .NET Core. These applications cannot be developed with Team Developer, or only with great effort.

Now these applications need to access SQLBase, which we have been doing via ADO.NET. It works, but you feel like you're back in prehistory. With Entity Framework, it's different: you save at least 40-50% of program code, development is much faster and you can no longer make many mistakes from the start that often happen under ADO.NET. As a result, the applications are not only developed faster, but they are also much more robust.

To make matters worse, Team Developer still does not support .NET Core, so you have to fall back on the old 4.8 (or 4.7?) framework if you need to develop DLLs with .NET.

That's really too many limitations for such an expensive product.

If we had an SQL database that supported both Team Developer and Entity Framework Core, our developer life would look much nicer and the family would be happy....

Comment: If not already, suggest you join our 'Team Developer SQLWindows Community Forum' https://forum.tdcommunity.net/index.php   ( Register and you get more options ).   You'll get more TD expertise / advice than you'll find here.

Comment: Sure, Entity Framework may be Ok ( I have no idea ), but OLEdB works just fine against most dBMS vendors ( If you go for SqlServer use the MSOLEDBSQL driver, not the old SQLOLEDB ) and Team Developer handles it well. Its fast and robust. Just assign your connection string to the SqlUDL variable ( or a UDL file path in there) and away you go. You don't need a SQL.ini at all, nor SqlUser, SqlPassword or SqlDatabase anymore

Comment: My (outdated) knowledge tells me that access from TD to other database systems is via ODBC. If it could be done with something else, that would be great. What about MySQL, Postgre and MariaDB?

Comment: I believe they all support OLEdB - which Microsoft is now developing more enhancements for future versions, in favour of ODBC. And the latest version of SQLServer OLEdB is faster than ODBC . TD works great with OLEdB.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. If this is the case, the "only" thing left is to replicate the ROWID in other RDBMs. That might be the biggest challenge for us. Surely we have one or the other SQL command that has to be rewritten, but even that should be finite.

None of this would be necessary if SQLBase supported Entity Framework. This was even announced in 2019 for version 12.3 - today no one wants to know about it!

Page 15 on the right:
[Announcement Version 12.3 – Entity Framework](https://www.md-consulting.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/OpenText-Gupta-State-of-the-Union-November-2019.pdf)

Comment: @SteveLeighton Thanks for your contribution to the internal (clinically dead) SQLBase forum. I replied an hour ago, but my post doesn't seem to be unlocked yet. Maybe it still will be.